# SBT sub project access root project data (dependency version)

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multiple [project](http://github.com/eleflow/uberdata), and I'm creating a class with it's git version in one of my subprojects.

```
def iUberdataCoreVersion(version: Option[String] = Some("Not a Git Repository"), dir: File) = {
  val file = dir / "UberdataCoreVersion.scala"
  IO.write(
    file,
    s"""package eleflow.uberdata.core\n  object UberdataCoreVersion{\n          val version = "${version.get}"\n
       val sparkVersion = ${allDependencies.value.filter(_.extraString.startsWith("spark")).head.crossVersion}
             |}\n""".stripMargin)
  Seq(file)
}
```

The dependencies are defined in the root project build.sbt file. I want to add spark version (one of my dependencies) into this file. Is there a way to pass an argument to a sub project build, or to iterate through the dependencies to discover which version of spark am I using?

**Update as required in comments**

The problem here is that in spark there is two versions, and at version 2 I can create it's context (to access the spark cluster) in a different way than it's in spark 1.

```
root
 build.sbt

lazy val subProject = project settings (libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-repl" % sparkVersion)
```

I have 3 sub projects, and the spark version is shared between them, that's why I've configured it this way, otherwise I could have inserted the dependencies into the subproject build file.

Consider that sparkVersion is provided as a build argument.

```
root
  sub
    build.sbt
```

Here in the subproject I want to create a file that contains the spark version. This can be done in a property file, or in a src code file, as I already do with git code. Can I receive it's value as a val when creating the sub project build?

I can access the spark version through it's context, it has a property for it, but in this specific case I want to do that before creating the context, and that's my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that your root project and sub-project use the same version? If so, you can put the version numbers in a property file and read the property file in the build.sbt of each sub-project

Comment: or just separate them into another file `dependencies.sbt` and then pick the ones you need for each project in the corresponding file, in other words put all deps with their versions in one place, and pick them as you wish. Note that all `.sbt` files in the root folder will be assembled together, so they have access to each other (just as if they were all in the same file).

Comment: @radumanolescu no in fact I'm trying to put the version of the lib in the code, because I need this before instantiating it's context class

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari if I separate the dependencies in another sbt, can I access it from a sub project?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example, showing what your Scala code needs to do? Usually, you have a dependency on `SomeLib_2.11-1.2.3.jar` in `build.sbt`, and that is the only place where you need to say what version it is. In your Scala class, you just `import com.someco.SomeClass` from the JAR, and you do not need to specify the version. Maybe I don't understand what you need

Comment: @dirceusemighini It depends on what you mean by `access it from sub project`. As mentioned by @radumanolescu you need to be more specific. You need to be aware of the version in the code? That's a whole different question which has nothing to do with the fact that your project is a sub-project. If you just want to use the dependency in a sub-project, answer is yes, all `.sbt` files have access to each other. You can easily find samples on sbt docs.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari By this I mean, that I have two project, and the dependency is defined at root, and I want to know how can I get this value in a subproject.

Comment: @radumanolescu Hi, I've just added a better explanation

Comment: Did you consider writing the version as val into Build.scala in the root project folder? Any sub project has access.

Comment: I do write the version as a val in the root build.sbt file, but I didn't knew that I could access it from subprojects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define properties in `build.properties` and use them in all subprojects. In this case, it's the Scala version - but it could be any string.

```
// ---------- ---------- multiproj/build.properties ---------- ---------- //
scala.version = 2.11.8
// ---------- ---------- multiproj/subproj/build.sbt ---------- ---------- //
val props = SettingKey[Map[String, String]]("props")

props := {
  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  val pf = new java.util.Properties()
  IO.load(pf, baseDirectory.value / ".." / "build.properties")
  pf.stringPropertyNames.map(p => p -> Option(System.getProperty(p)).getOrElse(pf.getProperty(p))).toMap
}

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library"  % props.value("scala.version") % "compile->*"
, "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % props.value("scala.version") % "compile->*"
)
```